# Issue with simple elixir/mix project

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Im learning Elixir and trying to compose a SIMPLE elixir hello world example but I keep running into this error when I do "mix run"

```
 (Mix) Could not start application collector:
       Collector.start(:normal, []) returned an error:
       shutdown: failed to start child: Collector.Sample
(EXIT) nil
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code minus the mix.exs and other non-critical files

```
defmodule Collector do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    Collector.Supervisor.start_link
  end
end
```

---

```
defmodule Collector.Supervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    children = [
      supervisor(Collector.Sample, [])
    ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

---

```
defmodule Collector.Sample do
  use Application

  def start_link do

  end

  def run do
    IO.puts "Hello World"
  end

end
```

I just wanna dump "Hello World" when I run "mix run" in the console and I dont know how or where to call the `run()` method. Thank you

Comment: You should take the Erlang tag off of the question; this has nothing to do with Erlang.  Try iex -S mix and then within iex, do your Collector.start

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci thank you. removed tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to build a command line app maybe [this blog post](http://abstraction.killedthecat.net/create-command-line-utility-elixir-mix/) will help you.

Other than that, supervisors are typically not used to run one-off processes, but rather to start workers like GenServers that can later be called. For example you could:

```
defmodule Collector.Supervisor do
  # ...

  def init(:ok) do
    children = [
      worker(Collector.Sample, [])
    ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

Then implement `Collector.Sample` as `GenServer`:

```
defmodule Collector.Sample do
  use GenServer

  # Client API

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def run do
    GenServer.call __MODULE__, :run
  end

  # GenServer callbacks

  def handle_call(:run, _from, state) do
    IO.puts "Hello World"
    {:reply, :ok, state}
  end
end
```

You can call the run method directly from `mix run` with the `-e` flag

```
mix run -e 'Collector.Sample.run'
```

Comment: Thank you for the direction and your time